# sql randomised data based on specific column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a user table. I want to pick 100 rows and then random those data. based on zip code.
Is there any way to randomize the data based on the zip code column

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by randomize by zipcode, if you mean select records with a specific zip and randomize...

```
SELECT Address, ZipCode
FROM Addresses
WHERE ZipCode = 90210
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 0, 100
```

This will return 100 address with the zip 90210 sorted in random order.